# appcfg does not support deploying to the Flexible environment

Tags: google-app-engine

I am following the tutorial given in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible). I have downloaded the code which is given in this github [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/firebase-appengine-backend), which is for backend.

As I could not import the backend code in Android Studios directly, I created one project and copied all the files present in src and webapp.

But when I try to deploy the code using Android Studios, I get the following error,

> 99% Deployments to App Engine Flexible require `env: flex` in app.yaml

I followed this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/upgrading), which tells to update app.yaml  by replacing the deprecated vm: true entry with env: flex. First thing is, I am not able to find the app.yaml. But I found similar entry in appengine-web.xml so I update that then I get the following error,

> appcfg does not support deploying to the Flexible environment

I am really not getting what wrong I am doing here.

Comment: Try using "gcloud app deploy", directly, after building your *.war file. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy

Comment: I tried after building war, it is not working either.
I am getting following error,
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) <War file name> could not be identified as a valid source directory or file